# Does your areas of research matter for graduate school?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

I know research is important for a Ph.D. program, but I'm wondering if research in a not-very-related field is still as useful?

For example, in the past I've done research in bioinformatics. I'm thinking of continuing just because I really like my advisor. However, I don't see my self doing a Ph.D. in that field. I am more interested in AI and/or embedded systems.

I am wondering if continuing to do work on a project in a field that I don't intend to do a Ph.D. in wouldn't be very helpful for me for grad school admissions, thus I should find a new project that will be more in line with my future interests.